# Forcefully checkout remote branch and make local exactly same as remote source

Tags: git, github, repository, bitbucket

I'm facing a strange problem
I have a development server that I and my team keep working on. This server is attached to a remote branch called Development in a bitbucket repository. The production server is attached to the same repository Master branch.

The source code of the Production and Development servers are bit different from the developers doing testings and updates firstly on the Development server.

Now I need to make the Production and Development server source code exactly the same and then continue working with new development. (Because previously they had bad practices with GIT)

To achieve this I created a New branch from the Master branch in my Repository and named it "STAGING"

Then I checked out that new branch from my Development server and then had a look at the source code. The source code still has some old development work files that only exist on the Development branch.

I tried every possible way to remove those and fetch this new branch as it is exactly in the repository but every time when I check the source code in the server it shows old files.

I tried removing the source code manually from the server and fetching new branch again.
I tried deleting local branch
I tried force checkout
I tried to rebase
I tried hard resetting the head
I tried git clean -f

now I'm out of options :(

Please help me with this. Thank you.